# Getting a dll to work in hta with vbs

Tags: dll, vbscript, hta

I'm trying to get a vbScript to work in an hta.

The vbs works fine when I run it independently, but when I try to use it in the hta, it is unable to load the dll file.

I have tried using regasm / codebase to register the dll but that didn't help either. Using regsvr32 is not an option as it cannot be run as an Administrator on the computers.

I'm using `ExecuteGlobal` to get the vbs file into the hta but I have also tried making a command that just runs the vbs from hta, but it still failed.

Have I overlooked something trivial?

Comment: If you are using a 64bit OS, check if the `mshta.exe` being executed is the 32bit or the 64bit version and that it matches the component and component registration

Comment: the error happens both when using the one in syswow64 and system32 folder.

Comment: okay, for some reason it was running the syswow64 even when i specified system32 to be run. i can do it by runing it via cmd now, does this mean i have to have another wrapper, telling it to open my hta with system32 rather than syswow64 if i want my users to be able to just click an icon to run it?

Comment: Execute `ftype htafile` to see that the default handler is placed in `syswow64`. You will need a wrapper, or change the registry or still better, use the same hta as a wrapper, making your hta determine if it is running in 32 or 64 bit version and if it is the wrong one start the right version and ending itself.

Comment: It looks like i will have to work with a wrapper in this case, from what i can find, windows have some issues identifying which mshta.exe is running, as they are named the same. I simpply called `%WinDir%\System32\mshta.exe c:\page.hta` in another vbs

Comment: You can try (to use your HTA as its own wrapper) with `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("PROCESS")("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")` and see if it returns `x86`

Comment: Thanks, I got the mshta to work correctly now. Now i just need to figure out how to pack everything into a single file. i tip my hat to you @MCND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when telling windows to run an hta it will automatically assume 32bit. to get it to work on 64bit systems use `%WinDir%\System32\mshta.exe c:\page.hta`

some sort of wrapper or launcher is needed to make sure you are running the correct mshta version

Answer (score 0):

You can register COM dlls with Regsvr32 (usually, but there are exceptions, like RTF 5 and later control). You can register .NET dlls pretending to be COM dlls with RegAsm. **Both require admin access**.

*.NET dlls register the core .NET dll as the COM handler, which dispatches the COM call to the .NET component DLL, unlike COM where nothing usually gets in the way.

To register a .NET dll without being admin requiresyou to export as a reg file from RegAsm (non admins can do). Search and replace `HKCR` with `HKCU\Software\Classes`. The reg file can then be merged by non admins.